# Why is the size of my Google Play Magazines app 357MB when it's empty on my S3?

Tags: internal-storage

When I look under the size of this app under Application Manager I see that the size is 357MB under data except that I had one magazine on it which I deleted but it still says the app is 300+MB!  What is the cause because the app is not 357MB itself. I'm running out of space so I need to fix it.  Any explanations?

OS: 4.1
S3

Comment: Did you try clearing the app data?

Comment: Don't forget about *app cache*, which I would clear first (to not lose any configuration). If that didn't help, I go with Al and delete the data as well. And if you really had 1 mag only and nothing else, step 3 would be uninstalling that app. For other helpful stuff on your low-storage-issue, I strongly recommend visiting our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info).

Comment: I've been using it for 2 months without checking data. I've got about 5 mags on it. The app size is 22MB and the Cache is 53MB. 300+ is a huge amount of data. AS Izzy said try the cache first then the app data. Failing that clear both and re-install the app I guess. What does the 'About App' scren show?

Comment: What do I lose if I delete cache? I deleted the data but it strange why the data was so huge!